# why does Enumerable.Except returns DISTINCT items?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Having just spent over an hour debugging a bug in our code which in the end turned out to be something about the [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method which we didn't know about:

```
var ilist = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
var ilist2 = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
ilist.Except(ilist2); // returns { 1 } as opposed to { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
```

or more generally:

```
var ilist3 = new[] { 1 };
var ilist4 = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
ilist4.Except(ilist3); // returns { 2, 3 } as opposed to { 2, 2, 3 }
```

Looking at the MSDN page:

> This method returns those elements in
>   first that do not appear in second. It
>   does not also return those elements in
>   second that do not appear in first.

I get it that in cases like this:

```
var ilist = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
var ilist2 = new[] { 1 };
ilist.Except(ilist2); // returns an empty array
```

you get the empty array because every element in the first array 'appears' in the second and therefore should be removed.

But why do we only get distinct instances of all other items that do not appear in the second array? What's the rationale behind this behaviour?

Comment: In my opinion, smells like a bug or unintended functionality. The MSDN page says not about a distinct result...

Comment: This isn't a bug. The `Except` method is intended to be translated into the SQL `EXCEPT` operator which is defined as a set operation. Being a set operation, only distinct elements are returned. The "distinctness" is implied by MSDN's use of the "set" terminology.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I certainly cannot say for sure why they decided to do it that way. However, I'll give it a shot.

MSDN describes Except as this:

> Produces the **set** difference of two
>   sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

A [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) is described as this:

> A set is a collection of **distinct**
>   objects, considered as an object in
>   its own right

Comment: +1 The implementation uses hashsets to reduce the problem from O(NxN) to O(N).